# Sequence of Recursion calls

Tags: c, quicksort

This will be dumb question, but I am having trouble to understand the sequence in which the recursion is called. For example in the quickSort algorithm, can somebody explain more detailed how it works. I will post the algorithm:

```
void quicksort(int a[],int low,int high)
{
    int pivot;
    if(high>low)
    {
        pivot=partition(a,low,high);
        quicksort(a,low,pivot-1);
        quicksort(a,pivot+1,high);
    }
}

int partition(int a[],int low,int high)
{
    int left,right;
    int pivot_item;
    int pivot=low;
    left=low;
    pivot_item=a[low];
    right=high;
    while(left<right)
    {
        while(a[left]<=pivot_item){
            left++;
        }
        while(a[right]>pivot_item){
            right--;
        }
        if(left<right){
            swap(a,left,right);
        }
    }
    a[low]=a[right];
    a[right]=pivot_item;
    return right;
}

int main()
{

    a[10]={5,1,13,14,7,6,19,10,9,23};
    int i;
    printf("before\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%i,",a[i]);
    }
    quicksort(a,0,10);
    printf("\n");
    printf("After sort:\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        printf("%i,",a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So it call the function with the array `a`, `low` is `0`, `high` is `10` and then the variable is assigned some value from the partition function ,then call `quicksort` again with `high` being `pivot-1` this time and it continues until `high` is `<= low` ,this is where the confusion is coming for me, how is the second call to `quicksort` excecuted since `high` is becoming equal to `low` and the `if` executes to false I think.

Comment: video explanation  : www.youtube.com/watch?v=y_G9BkAm6B8 // wikipedia page : en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_sort

Comment: I detect a hint of a misunderstanding here: "high is <= low". Keep in mind that `high` and `low` are *automatic variables* in both `quicksort()` and `partition()`. Each time one of these functions is called, the incoming values are copied into a new location. Changes made within a function invocation don't affect the caller's variables, even if they have the same name and even if the call is a recursive call to the same function. (Pointers can allow such modification, but you don't see any `&high` or `&low` here.)

Comment: Maybe add `void quicksort(int a[],int low,int high) { printf("qs l:%2d h:%2d >:%d\n", low, high,high>low);` and watch the results.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of recursion is so that you don't even have to think about the whole sequence of calls that the method takes.  you only have to think of the recursive relationship.

The questions that you should ask are:

1. Does the base case work?

   - Does `quicksort` correctly sort the array between `low` and `high` when `high` is not greater than(equal to) `low`?
2. Does the recursive relationship work?

   - Does `quicksort` correctly sort the array between `low` and `high`, if you assume that your other calls to `quicksort` work correctly?
   - You don't actually have to think about what path that they take.  Just assume, on faith, for now, that `quicksort(a,low,pivot-1);` correctly sorts array `a` between `low` and `pivot - 1`.  It might help you to think of it as a call to a completely different function, that completely sorts the array.

If both of those works, than your recursive function should work.  This goes for all recursive functions.